# How to determine new route after call router.navigate?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, observable

I'm trying to intercept a route change by router guard. So when I call:

```
this.router.navigate([“myApp/userProfiles”]);
```

So once called it goes through guard CanDeactivate interface. And the guard needs to determine where it's really going to redirect.
So is there a property something like:

```
this.router.newRoute ??
```

Or should I use a global variable to set it before call navigate method?

Comment: Could you expand on the *context* - what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I just want to catch some variables/state before user really leaves the page but just for certain cases, i.e. when he navigates to myApp/userPfofiles and ignore in all other cases so just navigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the `CanDeactivate` interface the fourth argument is the `nextState`. You can inspect it to find the next route's url.

```
interface CanDeactivate<T> { 
  canDeactivate(
    component: T, 
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, 
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

So in your case you can do something like this:

```
canDeactivate(
  component: TeamComponent,
  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
  nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {

  if (nextState.url === '/interesting/path/') {
    // do something
  else {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)